# Error on inserting Child record of Master Detail Relationship

Tags: master-detail

Error on inserting Child record  on custom object which is having Master Detail relationship with other Custom Object.

I have two custom Objects x and Y which are in Master Details Relations. There is on field on Custom Object Y say (z) which having Master detail Relation ship with x.

when I am inserting Y record without filling the 'z' field system throwing an error "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing"

When i give z=x.id and do insert, its throwing an error saying "Field does not exist"...

Let me know how can i fix it.

Comment: You should be doing something like `y.Z__c = z.Id;`.

Comment: I didn't get you  and the details provided above are related to Managed Package. I mean the custom objects are related to Managed Package

Comment: If your code is inside the managed package, field names will be e.g. `Abc__c`. If your code is outside the managed package, field names will be `XXX__Abce__c` when XXXsdhould be replaced with the managed package namespace.

Comment: Though i am giving the field name correctly it's system saying it doesn't exist while inserting the record.                                                                      I queried this field in Query editor to see records and it was showing up with the name as i mentioned. If i don't consider that field system throwing an error saying required fields is missing.But when i am saving this record in UI i am not encountering with any issues, record successfully saving.

Comment: One thing i noticed under the Setup-->Installed Package-->View Components-->Unused Components-->field showing with View Components section of Installed Package under  the Package Information as "Available in Versions 1.42 - 1.43 (Deprecated)". So i am thinking because it's deprecated it cannot be used.

Comment: Yep that makes sense.